# Mongodb update multiple documents with different values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been trying to use `updatemany` with mongoose. I want to update the values in database using an array of objects.

```
[
            {
                "variantId": "5e1760fbdfaf28038242d676",
                "quantity": 5

            },
            {
                    "variantId": "5e17e67b73a34d53160c7252",
                    "quantity": 13
            }
            ]
```

I want to use variantId as filter.
Model schema is:

```
let variantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    variantName: String,
    stocks: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0
    },
    regularPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    salePrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})
```

I want to filter the models using variantId and then decrease the stocks.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with an updateMany call since you need to decrement the stocks value for each document by a different number.

Comment: @Vidhyanshu jain : Why does your schema & sample document look completely different ? Do you need help with mongoose schema as well or just with query ?

Comment: @srinivasy that is not a sample document, instead it is a json that I receive and based on the json's value I will update the values.

Comment: @Vidhyanshujain : With what does this input `variantId` & `quantity` match with in actual document ?

Comment: @srinivasy variantId matches with the Object id of variant model. and quantity will decrease the stock by it's value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you need to update multiple documents with multiple criteria then `.updateMany()` wouldn't work - it will work only if you need to update multiple documents with same value, Try this below query which will help you to get it done in one DB call :

```
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");

let variantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    variantName: String,
    stocks: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0
    },
    regularPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    salePrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

const Variant = mongoose.model('variant', variantSchema, 'variant');

let input = [
    {
        "variantId": "5e1760fbdfaf28038242d676",
        "quantity": 5

    },
    {
        "variantId": "5e17e67b73a34d53160c7252",
        "quantity": 13
    }
]

let bulkArr = [];

for (const i of input) {
    bulkArr.push({
        updateOne: {
            "filter": { "_id": Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(i.variantId) },
            "update": { $inc: { "stocks": - i.quantity } }
        }
    })
}

Variant.bulkWrite(bulkArr)
```

**Ref :** [MongoDB-bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#examples)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seem to be working, nut I am facing another issue, after doing a blukwrite for queries that should throw error. Bulkwrite is not throwing errors.

Comment: @Vidhyanshujain : Bulkwrite will result in writerresult check the respose of query or documentation errors are thrown in writeErrors section, In that link check last few sections which are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done with a single `Model.updateMany` query. You will need to loop the array and use `Model.update` instead.

```
for (const { variantId, quantity } of objects) {
    Model.update({ _id: variantId }, { $inc: { stocks: -quantity } });
}
```

To run this in a transaction (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html), the code should look something like this (however I have not tried or tested this):

```
mongoose.startSession().then(async session => {
    session.startTransaction();

    for (const { variantId, quantity } of objects) {
        await Model.update({ _id: variantId }, { $inc: { stocks: -quantity } }, { session });
    }

    await session.commitTransaction();
});
```

Comment: this will be an asynchronus call, is there any way i can make is synchronus, as I have to use this in a transaction? @gutnar

Comment: I would go for the answer given by @srinivasy using bulkWrite instead which looks nicer.